# Estimating continuous mean from discrete and equidistant sample point of normal distribution.

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, means

i have an array of discrete measurements at regular intervals of a normal distribution. My question is how to estimate the mean (in terms of a continuous array index) of that distribution?

Currently I am multiplying the array indices by the corresponding measurements and dividing the sum of the resulting values by the sum of all available measurements. The reason I am posting this question is because the results seem off in a number of cases. Furthermore I expect the measurements to be noisy.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with my current approach.